# Methods from Reference project are not recognized: asp.net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, projects-and-solutions

i have two projects `Evolet.Domain` and `Evolet.Web` in my solution where `Evolet.Web` is asp.net mvc project that references the Domain project. But for every call from `Evolet.Web` to `Evolet.Domain` i get following compile time error message

```
'AddServiceCustomerAccount' accepting a first argument of type 'Evolet.Domain.Repositories.PartnerRepository' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  D:\Evolet\UserManagement\UserManagement\Controllers\MDMController.cs    149 44  Evolet.Web
```

i have added domain project as reference to my web project. i can't figure out what could be the problem.
Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about your methods are these `public` or `internal`. Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same assembly

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the Evolet.Domain and try again, and rebuild the Evolet.Web also. I faced similar situation recently and rebuilding solved the problem for me